# setState causing infinite loop in custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've created a custom hook within my **React** app, but for some reason when I update the internal `state` via an event listener, it causes an infinite loop to be triggered (when it shouldn't). Here's my code:

```
// Note that this isn't a React component - just a regular JavaScript class.
class Player{
    static #audio = new Audio();
    static #listenersStarted = false;
    static #listenerCallbacks = {
        playing: [],
        paused: [],
        loaded: []
    };

    static mount(){
        const loaded = () => {
            this.removeListenerCallback("loaded", loaded);
        };
        this.addListenerCallback("loaded", loaded);
    }
    
    // This method is called on the initialization of the React
    // app and is only called once. It's only purpose is to ensure
    // that all of the listeners and their callbacks get fired.
    static startListeners(){
        const eventShorthands = {
            playing: "play playing",
            paused: "pause ended",
            loaded: "loadedmetadata"
        };
        Object.keys(eventShorthands).forEach(key => {
            const actualEvents = eventShorthands[key];
            actualEvents.split(" ").forEach(actualEvent => {
                this.#audio.addEventListener(actualEvent, e => {
                    const callbacks = this.#listenerCallbacks[key];
                    callbacks.forEach(callback => {
                        callback(e)
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }
    static addListenerCallback(event, callback){
        const callbacks = this.#listenerCallbacks;
        if(callbacks.hasOwnProperty(event)){ 
            // Remember this console log
            console.log(true);
            this.#listenerCallbacks[event].push(callback);
        }
    }
    static removeListenerCallback(event, callback){
        const listenerCallbacks = this.#listenerCallbacks;
        if(listenerCallbacks.hasOwnProperty(event)){
            const index = listenerCallbacks[event].indexOf(callback);
            this.#listenerCallbacks[event].splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

const usePlayer = (slug) => {
    // State setup
    const [state, setState] = useReducer(
        (state, newState) => ({ ...state, ...newState }), {
            mounted: false,
            animationRunning: false,
            allowNextFrame: false
        }  
    );

    const _handleLoadedMetadata = () => {
        // If I remove this _stopAnimation, the console log mentioned
        // in the player class only logs true to the console 5 times.
        // Whereas if I keep it, it will log true infinitely.
        _stopAnimation();
    };

    const _stopAnimation = () => {
        setState({
            allowNextFrame: false,
            animationRunning: false
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        Player.addListenerCallback("loaded", _handleLoadedMetadata);
        return () => {
            Player.removeListenerCallback("loaded", _handleLoadedMetadata);
        };
    }, []);

    return {
        mounted: state.mounted
    };
};
```

This makes me think that the component keeps on re-rendering and calling `Player.addListenerCallback()`, but the strange thing is, if I put a `console.log(true)` within the `useEffect()` at the end, it'll only output it twice.

All help is appreciated, cheers.

Comment: For one, the identity of `_handleLoadedMetadata` changes on every render; you'll want to wrap it in `React.useCallback()`, and then add it as a ref to the `useEffect` call that hooks it up to the event listeners.

Comment: @AKX I had no idea this was a requirement. Care to elaborate on how I would do that in an answer?

Comment: Hmm... It might not be a requirement in this case since React guarantees the identity of a reducer dispatch function to not change, and the initial `useEffect` that's only called once should have captured the original `_handleLoadedMetadata` to clean up. But if you give it a shot and it helps with your issue, I can elaborate in an answer.

Comment: @AKX Could help. I'm not entirely sure how to use them within this context as I'm fairly new to React - which is why I think an answer would very much help!

Answer (score 2):

When you're hooking (pun unintended) up inner functions in React components (or hooks) to external event handlers, you'll want to be mindful of the fact that the inner function's identity changes on every render unless you use `useCallback()` (which is a specialization of `useMemo`) to guide React to keep a reference to it between renders.

Here's a small simplification/refactoring of your code that seems to work with no infinite loops.

- instead of a class with only static members, `Player` is a regular class of which there is an app-wide singletonesque instance.
- instead of hooking up separate event listeners for each event, the often-overlooked `handleEvent` protocol for `addEventListener` is used
- the hook event listener callback is now properly `useCallback`ed.
- the hook event listener callback is responsible for looking at the `event.type` field to figure out what's happening.
- the `useEffect` now properly has the ref to the callback it registers/unregisters, so if the identity of the callback does change, it gets properly re-registered.

I wasn't sure what the state in your hook was used for, so it's not here (but I'd recommend three separate state atoms instead of (ab)using `useDispatch` for an object state if possible).

The same code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so68741257-2zehg?file=/src/App.js) in a Codesandbox (with a base64-encoded example mp3 that I didn't care to add here for brevity).

```
const SMALL_MP3 = "https://...";

class Player {
  #audio = new Audio();
  #eventListeners = [];

  constructor() {
    ["play", "playing", "pause", "ended", "loadedmetadata", "canplay"].forEach((event) => {
      this.#audio.addEventListener(event, this);
    });
  }

  play(src) {
    if (!this.#audio.parentNode) {
      document.body.appendChild(this.#audio);
    }
    this.#audio.src = src;
  }

  handleEvent = (event) => {
    this.#eventListeners.forEach((listener) => listener(event));
  };

  addListenerCallback(callback) {
    this.#eventListeners.push(callback);
  }

  removeListenerCallback(callback) {
    this.#eventListeners = this.#eventListeners.filter((c) => c !== callback);
  }
}

const player = new Player();

const usePlayer = (slug) => {
  const eventHandler = React.useCallback(
    (event) => {
      console.log("slug:", slug, "event:", event.type);
    },
    [slug],
  );
  React.useEffect(() => {
    player.addListenerCallback(eventHandler);
    return () => player.removeListenerCallback(eventHandler);
  }, [eventHandler]);
};

export default function App() {
  usePlayer("floop");
  const handlePlay = React.useCallback(() => {
    player.play(SMALL_MP3);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={handlePlay}>Set player source</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The output, when one clicks on the button, is

```
slug: floop event: loadedmetadata 
slug: floop event: canplay
```

Comment: Upvoting purely based on the effort put into this answer - regardless of if it works - thank you! Will test it out now.

Comment: I've noticed that `handleEvent` is only used once in this. What's it accomplish?

Comment: It's simpler (and not having additional anonymous functions also saves a bit of memory). As mentioned in the prose, `addEventListener` also supports objects that have a `handleEvent` function as the listeners.